# Why some people use 'if has("gui_running")' in a .gvimrc?

Tags: vim

I've been reading some dotfiles (.vimrc .gvimrc) to learn some neat tricks, and I've come across [this one](https://github.com/nelstrom/dotfiles/blob/0bc0b1aa88c52d1b333bfb4ae8dcc9a8a5249f09/gvimrc):

```
if has("gui_running")
    set fuoptions=maxvert,maxhorz
    au GUIEnter * set fullscreen
endif
```

If this is already a .gvimrc (only loaded if gVim is loaded) why does it have the condition `if has("gui_running")`? Isn't this redundant? Is there an special issue/reason for that?

I know that `if has("gui_running")` is interesting to use in scripts and such, I'm asking specifically for it's uses in .gvimrc, because it's only sourced when I use gvim, so in theory, is not needed.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The gvimrc file that the OP linked to was mine, so I had better own up and admit that it was done for no good reason.

I copied that snippet from [Hacking without distractions](https://web.archive.org/web/20101119111748/http://amix.dk/blog/post/19403), which recommends putting it in your vimrc. Then at some point I realized it would be neater to move it into the gvimrc file, but I didn't think it through clearly and left the `if has('gui_running')` check in place. You're right to point out that it is unnecessary, so I have now removed it.

For the sake of posterity, here's my gvimrc [before](https://github.com/nelstrom/dotfiles/blob/0bc0b1aa88c52d1b333bfb4ae8dcc9a8a5249f09/gvimrc) and [after](https://github.com/nelstrom/dotfiles/blob/cb617070fcad7fb4a9c463a037232f8b858bde97/gvimrc) the change.

Comment: I started putting everything GUI related to gvimrc as well, I didn't unserstand the has('gui_running'). Thanks for passing by, and BTW, thanks for the great Vimcasts resources. Since you know so much about vim, I couldn't even think has('gui_running') was useless, I thought to myself, "it has to be a reason for that". :)

Answer (score 20):

Keeping one config file instead of two is easier (especially if you work on several machines, and need to keep their configs in sync).  So instead of creating `.gvimrc` **and** `.vimrc`, some might prefer to put it all into `.vimrc` file and use guards.

And then someone shares this file in the internet, and people copy GUI-relared sections of it to `.gvimrc`.  That's how it ends up  there.

Answer (score 12):

From vim-documentation, basically it allows you to do various settings depending on which gui that is running.

```
- To check in a Vim script if the GUI is being used, you can use something
  like this:

    if has("gui_running")
       echo "yes, we have a GUI"
    else
       echo "Boring old console"
    endif

                            *setting-guifont*
- When you use the same vimrc file on various systems, you can use something
  like this to set options specifically for each type of GUI:

    if has("gui_running")
        if has("gui_gtk2")
        :set guifont=Luxi\ Mono\ 12
        elseif has("x11")
        " Also for GTK 1
        :set guifont=*-lucidatypewriter-medium-r-normal-*-*-180-*-*-m-*-*
        elseif has("gui_win32")
        :set guifont=Luxi_Mono:h12:cANSI
        endif
    endif
```

UPDATE:

```
            *gui-init* *gvimrc* *.gvimrc* *_gvimrc* *$MYGVIMRC*
The gvimrc file is where GUI-specific startup commands should be placed.  It
is always sourced after the |vimrc| file.  If you have one then the $MYGVIMRC
environment variable has its name.
```

Comment: I can understand the uses of 'if has("gui_gtk2")'. But being in .gvimrc, why dont just call 'if has("gui_gtk2")' instead of 'if has("gui_running") if has("gui_gtk2")'? I'm interested to know why do people call 'if has("gui_running")' in a file that is only called when I'm already in a GUI. (.gvimrc it's only sourced if I'm using gvim, not vim)

Comment: the other viable answer might be that people are unaware of the initialization order, :help initialization and that some people are accustomed to keep all their settings in .vimrc (with the gui_running) and when moving them over to .gvimrc keep the gui_running by copy-paste...

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the case .gvimrc is read if you call start the program by using gvim
instead of vim? 
The only difference that I can see is if you are calling gvim in a setting where 
it cannot start (example, you are in ssh session without X). In that vim is going to be run, but the file might still be sourced.

(I don't really know if this is the case, in my system I have compiled vim without X, so I cannot test it)

Comment: It seens stupid to try to run gvim in a ssh session, but your argument is valid, I haven't thought of that.

Comment: @Somebody: Not necessarily. Some people use gvim over ssh with X forwarding, in which case gvim would pop up on the local X server.  This test could be a fall back for the case where X forwarding is not in place for whatever reason and vim launches instead.